# Java - Inherited Fluent method return type to return incident class' type, not parent's

Tags: java, inheritance, fluent

When you employ a fluent approach you might have the following scenario:

```
public class Foo<T extends a>{

    public Foo<T> someMethod(){
          System.out.println("foo");
          return this;
    }

}


public class Bar<T extends b> extends Foo<T> {

         public Bar<T> barMethod(){

            System.out.println("bar");
            return this;
         }

}


public class a{}
public class b extends a{}
```

A strength of a fluent interface is that you can chain method invocations, but whilst Bar has inherited someMethod(), the return type is Foo not Bar which would break the following chain:

```
new Bar<b>().someMethod().barMethod();
```

One answer could be to add @Overrides for every inherited method, such that Bar has the additional method:

```
 @Override
 public Bar<T> someMethod(){
          System.out.println("foo");
          return this;
    }
```

But in large classes, and extended class hierarchies this can prove a mess of redundancy surely?! Is there an appropriate return type to give to fluent methods whereby every class that inherits it will return an object of its specific type (so that we can chain methods without casts)?

I tried:

```
        public <U extends Foo<T>> U someMethod(){
          System.out.println("foo");
          return this;
    }
```

To alas, no avail. I am hoping someone knows of a simple and elegant solution to this problem. The project is large and so it needs to be maintainable and extensible if possible.

Thank you to any help you can provide in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this, if you don't mind an unchecked cast:

```
public class Foo<T, F extends Foo<T, F>> {
  public F someMethod() {
    System.out.println("foo");
    return (F) this; // <--- That's the unchecked cast! Tucked safely away.
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Bar<String>().someMethod().barMethod();
  }
}

class Bar<T> extends Foo<T, Bar<T>> {
  public Bar<T> barMethod() {
    System.out.println("bar");
    return this;
  }
}
```

Personally, I disable the unchecked cast warning globally for the whole project.

Comment: But still there is a `casting`, which OP doesn't want. I don't know why. Umm. But this casting is better. Its at one place. So, OP should be ok with it. Else Lord help him. ;)

Comment: @RohitJain see comment I made on above answer: It's a usability thing, trying to make it a very straightforward lib to use for a client to include in their project. Marko Topolnik's solution is interesting though, and something I hadn't considered. It seems casts of some description are unavoidable?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. Yeah that's why at the end of my comment, I added that its a better casting, as its at one place. :)

Comment: Sorry, answered before seeing the edit in your comment. Deleting mine.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik you say 'disable the unchecked cast warning globally', would that also propagate to client code so that they don't get any warnings when using the library in their project?

Comment: If the client only gets a JAR, it's already over, anyway, since this is a compile-time-only check inside the method implementation. From the outside you can't even detect it.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik the client would get just the JAR so this sounds like it would be sufficient, as I can guarantee that all unchecked casts inside the library are safe. Unlike say, if the client had to supply the type to cast to for a method.

Comment: BTW You don't have to disable the warnings at all, if it isn't to your taste. You can just annotate `someMethod` with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: Yes, as long as you make sure that everyone extends `Foo` as `ChildClass<T> extends Foo<T, ChildClass<T>>`, it will work.

Comment: Presumably, I would have to make Bar<T> into Bar<T, F extends Bar<T, F>> if I was to allow clients to extend further with a new subclass from Bar whilst retaining the fluency?

Comment: Yes, and the type parameters on the constructor get messy. I advise using a factory method such as `public static <X, Y extends Foo<X,Y>> Foo<X, Y> foo(Class<X> c) {
    return new Foo<X, Y>();
  }` Talk about **obfooscated** code!

Comment: What a mess! Would you mind just updating your answer it a sample of the factory method approach and why it might be advisable. Then I'll choose your answer, as it also matches similar approaches I just found elsewhere online for how to achieve this kind of thing! Thanks again for all your help today!

Comment: I ran into more difficulties with this approach... I'm still questioning whether it's actually workable with a deeper hierarchy.

Comment: The whole approach, or just the factory addition to it?

Comment: Factory was supposed to help, but it doesn't because the Y type will not get inferred. I can't find a way to parameterize `Foo` properly, only its subclasses. This is the same pattern as we have with `public abstract class Enum<T extends Enum<T>>`, but since it's abstract, this problem does not arise.

Comment: You've helped a lot with this issue, and despite it not quite being the elegant solution I was hoping for, this is an inherent problem with strongly typed languages it would seem. I think even with Bar<T, F extends Bar<T, F>> I can provide a static util method to instantiate it to a given type, such as MyBar() that will instantiate the object with the Type params, and all the client knows is they will get back a correctly instantiated MyBar obj. Whilst this requires a different static method for each specific Bar type, the list of plausible Bar types is known, so its not that problematic

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define `barMethod` method abstract so now you can call it on the `Foo` type.

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends a> {

    public Foo<T> someMethod() {
        System.out.println("foo");
        return this;
    }

    public abstract Foo<T> barMethod();
}
```

Now you can easily call

```
new Bar<b>().someMethod().barMethod();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it prevents us from instantiating Foo directly, which I need to be able to still do.

Comment: @HodeCode. So you don't want to add abstract method, you don't want to override, and you don't want to typecast. Hmmm. Will be tough, if there is a way. Let's see if someone can come up with a solution. But I don't think there is a workaround then, if you carve out all the workarounds. but still I can't be sure on that.

Comment: Then you will have to cast it.

Comment: That's a real shame that Java doesn't seem to facilitate this kind of architecture elegantly. I'm trying to make it as straightforward as possible for a client to use the library without any ugly code littered with casts etc.

Comment: @HodeCode It is good candidate for abstract class since you already have its children,and common functionality in Foo class.