# Fluent interface - return most specific return type

Tags: java, design-patterns, fluent, return-type

#### The situation:

I have a class hierarchy that looks a little bit like this. Note, my doesn't *really* look like this, I just wrote it this way to make it shorter and, in my opinion, more legible.

```
public abstract BaseClass {
    private Alpha a;
    private Beta b;

    public Alpha getAlpha() { return a; }
    public Beta getBeta() { return b; }
    public BaseClass setAlpha(Alpha a) { this.a = a; return this; }
    public BaseClass setBeta(Beta b) { this.b = b; return this; }
}

public Foo extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public Foo setBeta(Beta b) {
        super.setBeta(b);
        doSomethingElse();
        return this;
    }
    public Gamma getGamma() { return g; }
    public Foo setGamma(Gamma g) { this.g = g; return this; }
}

public Bar extends BaseClass {
    private Omega o;
    @Override
    public Bar setAlpha(Alpha a) {
        super.setAlpha();
        doSomethingElse();
        return this;
    }
    public Omega getOmega() { return o; }
    public Bar setOmega(Omega o) { this.o = o; return this; }
}
```

#### The problem:

There are many more of these methods then listed above. Notice that they don't conform to the same interface. The classes that use `Foo` and `Bar` and need to call `setGamma` and `setOmega` always have access to the most specific class. However, those same classes also need to call `setAlpha` and `setBeta`. Those methods don't return the correct type, however, unless I override them.

Options:

1. Override every method of `BaseClass` just to change the return type

   - Seems a lot of unnecessary code
2. Declare every method like `setGamma` and `setOmega` abstract in `BaseClass`. This might work, except then I'd have to define it for classes where it really makes no sense at all.
3. Similar to #2, except I don't declare these methods abstract, I give them an implementation - `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()`
4. Similar to #3, except I just ignore the problem rather than throwing an `Exception`.
5. Always all my builders with the most specific return types first. i.e. `someBar.setOmega().setAlpha()` but not `someBar.setAlpha().setOmega()`

All of these options seem gross. Does anyone have anything better?

Note: this situation is not quite like this one: [Java - Inherited Fluent method return type to return incident class' type, not parent's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118648/java-inherited-fluent-method-return-type-to-return-incident-class-type-not-p) as it's not really a generics issue.

Comment: If you need to call `doSomethingElse()` during `setBeta` or `setAlpha` you don't have a choice.

Comment: I think you could genericize `BaseClass` and have `setAlpha/Beta` return `<T>`, but I'm not up to coming up with the signature tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @chrylis noted in the comments, you can genericize `BaseClass`:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass> {
    private Alpha a;
    private Beta b;

    public Alpha getAlpha() {
        return a;
    }

    public Beta getBeta() {
        return b;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T setAlpha(Alpha a) {
        this.a = a;
        return (T) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T setBeta(Beta b) {
        this.b = b;
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

and extend as follows:

#### Foo:

```
public class Foo extends BaseClass<Foo> {
    private Gamma g;

    @Override
    public Foo setBeta(Beta b) {
        super.setBeta(b);
        doSomethingElse();
        return this;
    }

    private void doSomethingElse() { }

    public Gamma getGamma() {
        return g;
    }

    public Foo setGamma(Gamma g) {
        this.g = g;
        return this;
    }
}
```

#### Bar:

```
public class Bar extends BaseClass<Bar> {
    private Omega o;

    @Override
    public Bar setAlpha(Alpha a) {
        super.setAlpha(a);
        doSomethingElse();
        return this;
    }

    private void doSomethingElse() { }

    public Omega getOmega() {
        return o;
    }

    public Bar setOmega(Omega o) {
        this.o = o;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This introduces a couple unchecked cast warnings, which I suppressed.  It compiles, but I haven't tried actually doing anything with it.

Comment: I kind of like this. The one problem I see is that technically you could do `public class Baz extends BaseClass<Quux>`, which would cause `ClassCastException`s. Of course I would never do that, but it leaves the design vulnerable to such silly mistakes.

Comment: Yes, it's undeniably a bit fragile.

Comment: If your answer is option #6, which option would you choose if you were desigining this system?

Comment: I probably would do this.  It's not perfect, but I think it's better than the other choices.

Comment: If you're going to go this route make the base class generic argument `<T extends BaseClass<T>>` instead of `<T extends BaseClass>'.  I would also suggest only using this style in a controlled way rather than applying it to your whole architecture, because Java really doesn't handle fluent interfaces well due to generics issues.